# MySQL - Fetch Space Separated Field in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix, datetime

I have the following columns in MYSQL table:

```
ID    START_TIME
51    2015-01-01 01:00:00
```

I have the following MySQL query in Bash:

```
Values=($(mysql -DHISTORIZATION -hlocalhost -uroot -pAdmin -se "SELECT ID, START_TIME FROM TABLE_NEW WHERE ID=51"));
```

When I try to assign and print the values like this:

```
ID=Values[0];
START_TIME=Values[1];
echo $ID;
echo $ START_TIME;
```

It prints like  this:

```
51
2015-01-01
```

Ideally it should print like, which is the desired output:

```
51
2015-01-01 01:00:00
```

When I print

```
echo ${Values[*]};
```

It prints:

```
51 2015-01-01 01:00:00
```

Values contains three elements but it should contain two.
I think its the problem due the space character in "2015-01-01 01:00:00", but how to get rid of this? I would appreciate the answer without changing the IFS.

Thanks..

Comment: Try `Values=($(mysql -DHISTORIZATION -hlocalhost -uroot -pAdmin -se "SELECT ID, START_TIME FROM TABLE_NEW WHERE ID=51 ENCLOSED BY '\"'"));` I added `ENCLOSED BY '"'` to your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

mysql output is tab separated.
Thus, this should work:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -a Values < <(mysql -DHISTORIZATION -hlocalhost -uroot -pAdmin -se "SELECT ID, START_TIME FROM TABLE_NEW WHERE ID=51");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use variable that concatenate date & time.

```
echo ${value[*]};
2015-04-28 13:30:00

START_TIME=${value[0]}" "${value[1]}
```

I advise to use -N in mysql parameter so that it skip the column name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
IFS=$'\t'
Values=($(mysql -DHISTORIZATION -hlocalhost -uroot -pAdmin -se "SELECT ID, START_TIME FROM TABLE_NEW WHERE ID=51"))
ID=${Values[0]}
START_TIME=${Values[1]}
echo "$ID"
echo "$START_TIME"
```